# How to communicate and track the external bluetooth device state to iOS 8.4 application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, bluetooth, xcode6.4

I am working on VOIP application. I am using Xcode 6.4 with iOS 8.4 SDK.

My requirement is once call established in my application, i need to track whether external bluetooth is connected or not with my iPhone device as well as with my app. I need to communicate with external bluetooth device via my application in call active state. Like how native call and whats app doing in iOS. Same functionality im implementing. Also I need to track if bluetooth device terminated while call is active state in application.

I have tried somany ways by using `Corebluetooth` frame work. but, Only `centralManagerDidUpdateState` delegate method calling after that `didDiscoverPeripheral` not calling. I am unable to track the external device either turn off or turn on, but i am able to connecting after paired manually in settings. Could anyone suggest me a solution?

Comment: What does your device exactly? Since you're talking about VOIP, and since BLE (and CoreBluetooth.framework is only for BLE) is not suitable for AudioStreaming, it's quite unclear what you are trying to achieve... Are you talking about Headsets (AVAudioSession may be better)?

Comment: i need to communicate via bluetooth from my application while call is active,  is it clear?

Comment: Then, you mean that's you're looking to communicate with your device in background?

Comment: not background, even foreground also not working, i cant able to track the external device either turn off or turn on, but i am able to connecting after paired manually in settings

Comment: Is your device really Bluetooth Low-Energy? Can you find it with LightBlue (app on the AppStore that is good for BLE).

Comment: external bluetooth device is working for whats app call and native call

Comment: It doesn't mean it's Bluetooth Low-Energy. I may be only Bluetooth, as I suggested from the start.

Comment: im talking about bluetooth device which is low-energy and audio via bluetooth category route